# Elegant way to tell if something is false?

Tags: ruby

Seeing that `.nil?` is so useful and makes code so readable, I tried `.false?` and was surprised it didn't exist.

#### Question

What is the most elegant / preferred / self-documenting / idiomatic way to check if something is false in ruby, without using any user-defined methods?

#### Example

A possible use case replacing; the `s.false?` in this:

```rb
def false? 
  self == false
end

s ||= "hello" # is the same as

s = "hello" if (s.nil? || s.false?)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, usually you just compare to `false` only if it is actually important  whether the value is really `false` as in

```
if s == false
  do_something 
end
```

However, most of the time, people actually check for a value to be truthy or falsy as you often don't (need to) care for the strict difference between `false` or `nil`.

Here, you thus merely check whether a value is `nil` or `false` (that is: it's falsy) or if it is anything else (that is: it's truthy). This is encouraged by language idioms such as the checks done by `if` and `unless` as well as the common boolean operators such as `||` or `&&`.

```
do_something if s      # called if s is anything else but false or nil
do_something unless s  # called if s is either false or nil
```

Especially when accepting / expecting boolean values, a `nil` value is often handled as if it were `false` because of these Ruby language idioms.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most elegant / preferred / self-documenting / idiomatic
> way to check if something is false in ruby, without using any
> user-defined methods?

I think `s == false` is your answer plain and simple.